# How to use react error boundary in a react typscript application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to use the react error boundary in my typescript react app but it doesn't seem to be working. Whenever there is an error that breaks the application, the fallback UI does not get rendered

**ErrorBoundary.tsx**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
class ErrorBoundary extends Component<{children:JSX.Element}, { hasError: boolean }> {
     constructor(props: { children: JSX.Element; } | Readonly<{ children: JSX.Element; }>) {
       super(props)
     
       this.state = {
          hasError: false
       };
       
     }
     static getDerivedStateFromError(error: any) {
          return { hasError: true };
     }
    
  render() {
     if(this.state.hasError == true){
          return <h1>Something went wrong</h1>
     }else{
         return this.props.children;
     }
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { useContext, useState, useEffect, FC} from 'react';
import { AccessContexts } from './components/Contexts';
import Context from './components/Contexts';
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import ErrorBoundary from './components/ErrorBoundary';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
function App(){
  return (
    <AccessContexts>
        <MyRoutes />
    </AccessContexts>
  );
}

export default App;
function MyRoutes() {
  
     return (
      <div className="App">
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />}/>
            </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </div>
     )
}
```

I am using the **ErrorBoundary** component in **MyRoutes**

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check when you get error because Error boundaries do not catch errors for: Event handlers , Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout), Server side rendering, Errors thrown in the error boundary itself

Comment: I have checked and it dosen't seem to have any error

Comment: you wrote "Whenever there is an error that breaks the application" - I speak about this error. if you add `throw 'some error'` before the return statement in  Dashboard component, do you see the fallback UI?